# Scandit BarcodeScanner: Class not found

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to implement the [Scandit BarcodeScanner for PhoneGap](https://github.com/Scandit/BarcodeScannerPlugin), but I am getting this error:

`Failed : Class not found`

I've red somewhere on the internet that I had to add this to my config.xml:

`<plugin name="BarcodeScanner" value="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner" />`

However this did not solve it.

What am I doing wrong?

---

## EDIT

It seemed like I had installed the wrong SDK, Installed the right one now, but I can't build my app anymore. It gives me this error:

`Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,C:\Users\arko\testap
p\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8`

Answer (score 0):

We resolved this with Arko over mail. It seems cleaning the project in Eclipse finished the issue in the

Answer (score 0):

For me, the cause of the "Error code 1 for command: cmd with args..." error was an invalid icon path and an invalid theme in AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while using the .startScanning() method.

And just like you, I had added the wrong pluging to my project (donwloaded the phonegap windows version only, instead of phonegap version - that contains android, ios and windows platforms).

I've just removed the plugin and add the correct one and it's working as expected.